# При выборе из selecta radioButton должен принять нужное ему значение

Tags: javascript, html

Kак сделать, чтобы при выборе из selecta radioButton принимал нужное ему значение?

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="name" value="1">Разработка сайта</label>
</div>
<label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="name2">
    <option>Landing page</option>
    <option>Интернет-магазин</option>
    <option>Корпоративный сайт</option>
  </select>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="name" value="2">Мобильное приложение</label>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="name3">
    <option>iOS</option>
    <option>Android</option>
    <option>Android + iOS</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
             <script>
function myFunction1() {
     document.getElementById("radio_button").checked = true;
}
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("radio_button2").checked = true;

}
</script>
```

Comment: ну и добавить onclick на select, сразу скажу может это очень большой костыль, ну я не знаю  js  и сделал это за 5 минут. Если кто подправит буду рад

Comment: Или вам нужно отправить value из select в radio? Типа чтобы значение radio стало Landing page?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="name" value="1" id="check1">Разработка сайта</label>
</div>
<label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="name2">
    <option>Landing page</option>
    <option>Интернет-магазин</option>
    <option>Корпоративный сайт</option>
  </select>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="name" value="2" id="check2">Мобильное приложение</label>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="name3">
    <option>iOS</option>
    <option>Android</option>
    <option>Android + iOS</option>
  </select>



<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.querySelector('#check1');
var y =  document.querySelector('#check2');
var c = document.querySelector('#sel1');
c.addEventListener('click', function () {
 x.checked = true;
});
document.querySelector('#sel2').addEventListener('click', function () {
 y.checked = true;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```